# Cannot bind filters on Ext.chart.CartesianChart

Tags: extjs

I am new to Ext JS working on Sencha 6.5(Ext js 6.2), while running my code I am getting error as :

Ext.mixin.Bindable.applyBind(): Cannot bind filters on Ext.chart.CartesianChart - missing a setFilters method.

The chart in tab1 works fine. Further what I am trying to do is, binding the selection from combo box in tab2 to cartesian chart in next tab, I am getting the error. Can any one help please, Thanks in advance,  my code is :

Store : 2FAData.js

```
Ext.define('LICApp.store.2FAData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.2fa-data',
    storeId: 'myStore',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.reader.Xml'
    ],

    autoLoad: false, // Set it to false


    fields: ['name','cnt', 'zone'],

       proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        cors: 'true',
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/BiodataController/bio',
        method: 'POST',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'biodata',
            rootProperty: 'biodatas'
        }
    }
});
```

Basic.js

```
Ext.define('LICApp.view.charts.bar3d.Basic', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'bar-basic-3d',
    controller: 'bar-basic-3d',

    requires: [
        'Ext.chart.theme.Muted',
        'LICApp.store.2FAData',
        'LICApp.store.Chartdata'

    ],

    //width: 1300,
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: { anchor: '-30' },

    referenceHolder: true,
    viewModel: true,
    config: {
        value: false
    },


    items: [{
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        title: 'Consolidated View',
        reference: 'chart',
        theme: 'Muted',
        width: '100%',
        height: 700,
        legend: {
            docked: 'right'
        },
        animation: Ext.isIE8 ? false : {
            easing: 'backOut',
            duration: 500
        },
        store: {type: 'chartdata',autoLoad:true},
        insetPadding: 40,
        flipXY: true,
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric3d',
            position: 'bottom',
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0,
            //maximum: 100,
            //majorTickSteps: 10,
            renderer: 'onAxisLabelRender1'
        }, {
            type: 'category3d',
            position: 'left',
            grid: true
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar3d',
            fullStack: false,
            title: [ 'Concurrencia Enabled', 'eFeap Enabled', 'Authorised Users', 'Biometric Enrolled Users', 'Total Devices Issued', 'Total No. of Employees'],
            xField: 'zone',
            yField: [ 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6'],
            axis: 'bottom',
            stacked: false,
            highlight: true,
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                renderer: 'onSeriesTooltipRender1'
            }
        }],
        sprites: [{
            type: 'text',
            text: '2FA Biometric Progress - Zonewise comparison',
            fontSize: 22,
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            x: 450, // the sprite x position
            y: 20  // the sprite y position
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Source: 2FA Data Server',
            fontSize: 10,
            x: 12,
            y: 695
        }]
    },

    {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            title : 'Zone Selection',
            reference: 'zone',
            fieldLabel: 'Choose Zone',
            store: {
                type: 'chartdata',autoLoad:true
            },
            valueField: 'zone',
            displayField: 'zone',
            publishes: 'value',
            typeAhead: true,
            queryMode: 'local',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText: 'Select a Zone...',
            selectOnFocus: true,
            //width: 300,
            indent: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                select: 'onZoneSelected'
                        }
        },

        {
        xtype: 'cartesian',
        itemId: 'zchart',
        title: 'Zonewise View',
        flipXY: true,
        reference: 'chart',
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        insetPadding: '40 40 30 40',
        innerPadding: '3 0 0 0',
        theme: {
            type: 'muted'
        },

        store: {
            type: '2fa-data', autoLoad :true
        },
        bind: {
            visible: '{zone.value}',
            filters: {
                property: 'zone',
                value: '{zone.value}'

            }
        },
        animation: {
            easing: 'easeOut',
            duration: 500
        },
        interactions: ['itemhighlight'],
        axes: [{
            type: 'numeric3d',
            renderer: 'onAxisLabelRender',
            title: 'Number of Employees',
            grid: {
                odd: {
                    fillStyle: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0)'

                },
                even: {
                    fillStyle: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)'

                }
            }
        }, {
            type: 'category3d',
            position: 'left',
            label: {
                textAlign: 'right'
            },
            grid: true
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'bar3d',
            xField: 'name',
            yField: 'cnt',
            style: {
                minGapWidth: 10
            },
            highlight: true,
            label: {
                field: 'cnt',
                display: 'insideEnd',
                renderer: 'onSeriesLabelRender'
            },
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                renderer: 'onSeriesTooltipRender'
            }
        }],
        sprites: [{
            type: 'text',
            text: '2FA Biometric - Zonewise Progress Chart',
            fontSize: 22,
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            x: 40, // the sprite x position
            y: 20  // the sprite y position
        }, {
            type: 'text',
            text: 'Source: 2FA Data Server',
            fontSize: 10,
            x: 12,
            y: 490
        }]

    }

    ]

});
```

BasicController.js

```
Ext.define('LICApp.view.charts.bar3d.BasicController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.bar-basic-3d',

    onAxisLabelRender: function (axis, label, layoutContext) {
        return Ext.util.Format.number(layoutContext.renderer(label) );
    },

    onSeriesLabelRender: function (v) {
        return Ext.util.Format.number(v);
    },

    onSeriesTooltipRender: function (tooltip, record, item) {
        var formatString = '0,000 ';

        tooltip.setHtml(record.get('name') + ': ' +
            Ext.util.Format.number(record.get('cnt'), formatString));

    },

    onPreview: function () {
        if (Ext.isIE8) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Unsupported Operation', 'This operation requires a newer version of Internet Explorer.');
            return;
        }
        var chart = this.lookupReference('chart');
        chart.preview();

            },



     onItemSelected: function (sender, record) { 

                var zone = sender.getValue();
                Ext.toast('You selected : ' + zone);
                var store =  Ext.getStore('myStore');
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/BiodataController/bio?zone='+zone,
                timeout: 60000,
                method: 'GET',
                scope: this,
                reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: 'biodata',
                rootProperty: 'biodatas'
                },



                success: function(resp, request) {
                    var data = console.log(resp.responseText);
                    var myView = Ext.getCmp('zchart');
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Data return from the server: '+ resp.responseText);

                    store.reLoad();//reload will be called, when AJAX call is successful.



/*

                if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
                    tmp = new DOMParser();
                    xml = tmp.parseFromString( resp.responseText , "text/xml" );
                } else { // IE
                    xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
                    xml.async = "false";
                    xml.loadXML( resp.responseText );
                }
*/

                autoLoad:true;

                //store.load(resp.responseText);
                    //console.log(myView);
                    //store.setData(resp.responseText);
                    },


                    failure: function(resp, opts) {
                    },

                    callback: function(options, success, resp) {
                    }


                });

            },



onCombo1Selected: function (sender, record) { 

                var zone = sender.getValue();
                Ext.toast('You selected : ' + zone );

            },

onCombo2Selected: function (sender, record) { 

                var divn = sender.getValue();
                Ext.toast('You selected : ' + divn + '-' + record.get('donm'));

            },

onCombo3Selected: function (sender, record) { 

                var bran = sender.getValue();
                Ext.toast('You selected : '  + record.get('bran'));

            },            

onZoneSelected: function (sender, record) { 

                var zone = sender.getValue();
                Ext.toast('You selected : ' + zone );

            },            

// Controller entries for stacked bar


    onAxisLabelRender1: function (axis, label, layoutContext) {
        // Custom renderer overrides the native axis label renderer.
        // Since we don't want to do anything fancy with the value
        // ourselves except appending a '%' sign, but at the same time
        // don't want to loose the formatting done by the native renderer,
        // we let the native renderer process the value first.
        return layoutContext.renderer(label) ;
    },

    onSeriesTooltipRender1: function (tooltip, record, item) {
        var fieldIndex = Ext.Array.indexOf(item.series.getYField(), item.field),
            zone = item.series.getTitle()[fieldIndex];

        tooltip.setHtml(zone + ' of ' + record.get('zone') + ': ' +
            record.get(item.field) + ' out of ' + record.get('data6') + ' Total');
    },



    onColumnRender1: function (v) {
        return v ;
    }
// Ends here



});
```

Comment: Exactly what it says. There is no "filters" config on the chart. It needs to be on the store.

Comment: Can u plz guide the exact syntax plz.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work the way you want it to.
The Cartesian Graph doesn't have it's own filtering mechanism and thus you can't trigger the filter via data binding. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know, you can't set child elements' properties such as the store's filter property via data-binding)

You'll have to take the oldschool route and set the filters by hand in the ComboBox's Listener like this:

```
onZoneSelected: function (sender, record) { 
    var zone = sender.getValue();
    Ext.toast('You selected : ' + zone );

    var zchart = sender.up().getComponent('#zchart');
    zchart.store.setFilters([{property: 'zone', value: zone}]);
},
```

Comment: Still giving the error as : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined at   zchart.store.setFilters([{property: 'zone', value: zone}]);

Comment: How this filter will be passed on to the store parameter in view i.e. Basic.js